# Create a pyspark dataframe index when appending to creating a db table

Tags: pyspark

I've gotten really slow access for a select statement, which I suspect must be down to the db table not having an index. How can I use one of the existing columns to index upon (say an existing customer number).

```
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(results_df).set_index('company_id')
```

which gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

How can I push down indexing with the subsequent command:

```
df_spark.write.option('header','true').saveAsTable(name="db.table", mode="append")
```

Comment: set_index is the pandas operation, pyspark follows a different execution plan. it may not be recommended to force the index with pyspark. however you may be able to create a sequential index column

Comment: The base table is parquet, so could be partioned, but doing this on company_id would create too many files and too many partitions but it is only the lookup field that is needed.